# my php file is not working within my app that i have created with phonegap

Tags: php, angularjs, json, database, cordova

I am using phonegap to create a music/sound player application for android. I am using html5 css and angular.js.

I have all the details of the sounds in a content management system on a web server so ideally i would like to use php within the app to retrieve information from the CMS and then create a json file from the CMS content so that angular can work with it on the client side.
so I started off by trying to make a php file work within the app but i am having trouble.
I have hard coded a json string into the php file for testing purposes (instead of doing an SQL statement to retrieve info from the database). I am using angular's $http method to get the json data "echod" back from the php file.

This is working perfect when testing on my computer however when i test the app on my phone after building with phonegap it is not getting the json data from the php file.

I have read that you can use php within phonegap. But i am new to both phonegap and angular so maybe there is something obvious i am doing wrong.

Also is it better to use a local database on the device?

sounds.php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$output = '{"sounds": [{"title": "Alarm", "soundType": "Sound Effect", "index": "0", "mp3": "sounds/0001_alarm_high_squeak.mp3"},';

$output .= '{"title": "Alarm 2", "soundType": "Sound Effect", "index": "1", "mp3": "sounds/0001_alarm_high_squeak.mp3"},';
$output .= '{"title": "Alarm 2", "soundType": "Sound Effect", "index": "1", "mp3": "sounds/0001_alarm_high_squeak.mp3"}]}';

echo $output;
?>
```

controller.js:

```
 //create a module using the Angular objects module() method
    var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);

myApp.factory("soundsFactory", function($http){
    return {
        getSounds: function(callback){
            $http.get('http://www.example.com/iwp/my_app_php/sounds.php').success(callback);
        }
    };
});

//create and register our controller with this module
myApp.controller("workshopController", function($scope, soundsFactory){

    /*var sounds = [{title: 'Alarm', soundType: 'Sound Effect', index: '0', mp3: 'sounds/0001_alarm_high_squeak.mp3'}, 
            {title: 'Alarm 2', soundType: 'Sound Effect', index: '1', mp3: 'sounds/0002_alarm_high.mp3'},
            {title: 'Mumble', soundType: 'Voice', index: '2', mp3: 'sounds/0003_alarm_low.mp3'}];

    */

    var player = document.getElementById('audio_player');
    $scope.player = player;

    soundsFactory.getSounds(function(results){
        $scope.sounds = results.sounds;
        //alert($scope.sounds);
    });

    $scope.playmusic = function($index){
        var mp3 = $scope.sounds[$index].mp3;
        $scope.selectedIndex = $index;

        $scope.player.setAttribute('src', mp3);

        //load the player after inserting the new mp3 file
        $scope.player.load();
        $scope.player.play();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="workshopController"> 
    <div>
        <ul>

            <!--want to add the class 'on' when user selects an item so we can style the selected item-->
            <li id='item_number0' class='item_row' ng-class="{'on': $index == selectedIndex}" data-ng-repeat="currentSound in sounds" data-ng-click="playmusic($index)">

            <span id='select_item{{currentSound.index}}'>

                <span class='item-column column-xxs-1'><i class='fa fa-play'></i></span>
                <span class='item-column column-xxs-5'>
                    <span class='item_col_split'>{{currentSound.title}}</span>
                    <span class='item_col_split'>{{currentSound.soundType}}</span>
                </span>         
                <span class='item-column column-xxs-2'>{{currentSound.index}}</span>
            </span>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

        <audio id ='audio_player'>
            <source id='src_mp3' type='audio/mp3' src=''/>
            <source id='src_ogg' type='audio/ogg' src=''/>
            <object id='audio_object' type='audio/x-mpeg' width='200px' height='45px' >
                <param id = 'param_src' name='src'/>
                <param id = 'param_src' name='src'/>
                <param name='autoplay' value='false' />
                <param name='autostart' value='false' />
            </object>
        </audio>

</div><!--/controller-->
```

Comment: is phone networked to be able to access your localhost?

Comment: do you mean: is my phone connected to the internet when i open the app? yes it is...

Comment: No... I mean is it connected to local network that can access your localhost server? Your localhost server is not available via internet

Comment: I'm not sure. how would i do that? thanks

Comment: Just to elaborate. I haven't been doing any advanced testing on the phone, purely on my computer browser. and then i zip up the app project and use build.phonegap.com to create the app file and scan the QR code onto my phone and the app icon appears and I can open the app there to see if its working. currently the json data from the php file is not being retrieved.

Comment: Well your phone has no access to your server then

Comment: do you know how to fix this issue? thanks

Comment: Read up on how to connect phone tto localhost through your wifi network based on your operating system

Comment: @charlietfl ok thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Sarah Even if you are able to crack this issue, i feel you will not able to play sound in device until you use cordova media plugin

Comment: @Gandhi thanks actually the sound is playing fine on the device with the hardcoded json. i'm using html5 audio. :)

Comment: @Sarah Glad it worked. It works fine is both iOS and Android?

Comment: @Gandhi  I havent tried working with phonegap and iOS yet. I just started using the trial version of phonegap yesterday. hopefully i will try iOS out when i get further into developing. however previously I have made a html5 audio mobile Website which plays perfect on iphone too but i havent tried it out with phonegap yet. I think it should work. thanks :)

Comment: @Sarah Playing audio using mobile browser and playing audio from a mobile app are different ball games. But since you have expertise in HTML5 audio, it should not be a problem for you. But when you get a chance, try out media plugin. It gives more control when you are developing hybrid apps. Gud luck and happy coding. Cheers

Comment: @Gandhi ok thanks a lot. i will let you know if it works in future and i will also try out the media plugin soon. thanks

Comment: @Sarah Sure.Thanks. Hope to catch up soon on some other issue discussion :)

Comment: @charlietfl Hi. I am a bit confused about the server issue still. would you be able to explain to me please why does my phone need to be able to access the local server when the php file that i am trying to access is uploaded to a web server that is accessible globally?

Comment: OK...I didn't realize the php was running on web accessible server. You had only mentioned running local

Comment: @charlietfl that's ok I probably wasn't clear enough about that. i will investigate further..

Comment: Haven't done any phone gap for long time but I think you also need to whitelist accessible domains in your config

Comment: @charlietfl thanks. I read somewhere that i need this in my config file: <access origin="*" /> but that is already there so it must be something else..

Comment: I got this working. I had the config file outside the www folder by mistake.